# Cyclometic complexity huge - clone object better approach?

Tags: java

My metric tool says that the copyTo() method has a cyclomatic complexity of 44. That's quite huge. 
How can I create a clone of my address object using a better and faster approach? Note: I don't have the Cloneable interface available(mobile app).

Here is the class:

```
class Address
{
    Address()
    {
        init();
    }

    String company1;
    String company2;
    String degree;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String salutation;
    String toPerson;
    String poBox;
    String country;
    String postalCode;
    String place;
    String street;
    String telephone1;
    String telephone2;
    String mobilePhone;
    String privatePhone;
    String fax;
    String eMail;
    String homepage;
    String socialSecurityNumber;
    String bank1Name;
    String bank1BCN;
    String bank1AccountNr;
    String bank2Name;
    String bank2BCN;
    String bank2AccountNr;
    String free01Name;
    String free01Value;
    String free02Name;
    String free02Value;
    String free03Name;
    String free03Value;
    String free04Name;
    String free04Value;
    String free05Name;
    String free05Value;
    String comment;
    String cityCode;
    GpsPosition position;
    int recId;
    int recStatus;
    DateTime recCreated;
    String recCreatedBy;
    String recCreatedByProg;
    DateTime recChanged;
    String recChangedBy;
    String recChangedByProg;
    AddressPropertyUsage usage;

    /* Generates a duplicate of the Address object */
    Address clone()
    {
        Address clonedObject = new Address();

        copyTo(clonedObject);

        return clonedObject;
    }

    void copyTo(Address destination)
    {
        if (destination.usage == null)
            destination.usage = new AddressPropertyUsage(this.usage.value);
        else
            destination.usage.value = this.usage.value;

        destination.recId = this.recId;
        destination.recStatus = this.recStatus;
        destination.recChanged = this.recChanged.clone();

        if (this.recChangedBy == null)
            destination.recChangedBy = null;
        else
            destination.recChangedBy = this.recChangedBy.substring(0);

        if (this.recChangedByProg == null)
            destination.recChangedByProg = null;
        else
            destination.recChangedByProg = this.recChangedByProg.substring(0);

        destination.recCreated = this.recCreated.clone();

        if (this.recCreatedBy == null)
            destination.recCreatedBy = null;
        else
            destination.recCreatedBy = this.recCreatedBy.substring(0);

        if (this.recCreatedByProg == null)
            destination.recCreatedByProg = null;
        else
            destination.recCreatedByProg = this.recCreatedByProg.substring(0);

        if (this.company1 == null)
            destination.company1 = null;
        else
            destination.company1 = this.company1.substring(0);

        if (this.company2 == null)
            destination.company2 = null;
        else
            destination.company2 = this.company2.substring(0);

        if (this.degree == null)
            destination.degree = null;
        else
            destination.degree = this.degree.substring(0);

        if (this.firstName == null)
            destination.firstName = null;
        else
            destination.firstName = this.firstName.substring(0);

        if (this.lastName == null)
            destination.lastName = null;
        else
            destination.lastName = this.lastName.substring(0);

        if (this.street == null)
            destination.street = null;
        else
            destination.street = this.street.substring(0);

        if (this.postalCode == null)
            destination.postalCode = null;
        else
            destination.postalCode = this.postalCode.substring(0);

        if (this.place == null)
            destination.place = null;
        else
            destination.place = this.place.substring(0);

        if (this.country == null)
            destination.country = null;
        else
            destination.country = this.country.substring(0);

        if (this.poBox == null)
            destination.poBox = null;
        else
            destination.poBox = this.poBox.substring(0);

        if (this.telephone1 == null)
            destination.telephone1 = null;
        else
            destination.telephone1 = this.telephone1.substring(0);

        if (this.telephone2 == null)
            destination.telephone2 = null;
        else
            destination.telephone2 = this.telephone2.substring(0);

        if (this.mobilePhone == null)
            destination.mobilePhone = null;
        else
            destination.mobilePhone = this.mobilePhone.substring(0);

        if (this.fax == null)
            destination.fax = null;
        else
            destination.fax = this.fax.substring(0);

        if (this.eMail == null)
            destination.eMail = null;
        else
            destination.eMail = this.eMail.substring(0);

        if (this.homepage == null)
            destination.homepage = null;
        else
            destination.homepage = this.homepage.substring(0);

        if (this.salutation == null)
            destination.salutation = null;
        else
            destination.salutation = this.salutation.substring(0);

        if (this.toPerson == null)
            destination.toPerson = null;
        else
            destination.toPerson = this.toPerson.substring(0);

        if (this.privatePhone == null)
            destination.privatePhone = null;
        else
            destination.privatePhone = this.privatePhone.substring(0);

        if (this.comment == null)
            destination.comment = null;
        else
            destination.comment = this.comment.substring(0);

        if (this.cityCode == null)
            destination.cityCode = null;
        else
            destination.cityCode = this.cityCode.substring(0);

        this.position.copyTo(destination.position);

        if (this.bank1AccountNr == null)
            destination.bank1AccountNr = null;
        else
            destination.bank1AccountNr = this.bank1AccountNr.substring(0);

        if (this.bank1BCN == null)
            destination.bank1BCN = null;
        else
            destination.bank1BCN = this.bank1BCN.substring(0);

        if (this.bank1Name == null)
            destination.bank1Name = null;
        else
            destination.bank1Name = this.bank1Name.substring(0);

        if (this.bank2AccountNr == null)
            destination.bank2AccountNr = null;
        else
            destination.bank2AccountNr = this.bank2AccountNr.substring(0);

        if (this.bank2BCN == null)
            destination.bank2BCN = null;
        else
            destination.bank2BCN = this.bank2BCN.substring(0);

        if (this.bank2Name == null)
            destination.bank2Name = null;
        else
            destination.bank2Name = this.bank2Name.substring(0);

        if (this.socialSecurityNumber == null)
            destination.socialSecurityNumber = null;
        else
            destination.socialSecurityNumber = this.socialSecurityNumber.substring(0);

        if (this.free01Name == null)
            destination.free01Name = null;
        else
            destination.free01Name = this.free01Name.substring(0);

        if (this.free01Value == null)
            destination.free01Value = null;
        else
            destination.free01Value = this.free01Value.substring(0);

        if (this.free02Name == null)
            destination.free02Name = null;
        else
            destination.free02Name = this.free02Name.substring(0);

        if (this.free02Value == null)
            destination.free02Value = null;
        else
            destination.free02Value = this.free02Value.substring(0);

        if (this.free03Name == null)
            destination.free03Name = null;
        else
            destination.free03Name = this.free03Name.substring(0);

        if (this.free03Value == null)
            destination.free03Value = null;
        else
            destination.free03Value = this.free03Value.substring(0);

        if (this.free04Name == null)
            destination.free04Name = null;
        else
            destination.free04Name = this.free04Name.substring(0);

        if (this.free04Value == null)
            destination.free04Value = null;
        else
            destination.free04Value = this.free04Value.substring(0);

        if (this.free05Name == null)
            destination.free05Name = null;
        else
            destination.free05Name = this.free05Name.substring(0);

        if (this.free05Value == null)
            destination.free05Value = null;
        else
            destination.free05Value = this.free05Value.substring(0);
    }


    private void init()
    {
        this.company1 = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.company2 = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.degree = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.firstName = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.lastName = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.salutation = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.toPerson = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.poBox = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.country = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.postalCode = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.place = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.street = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.telephone1 = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.telephone2 = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.mobilePhone = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.privatePhone = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.fax = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.eMail = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.homepage = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.bank1Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.bank1BCN = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.bank1AccountNr = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.bank2Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.bank2BCN = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.bank2AccountNr = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free01Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free01Value = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free02Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free02Value = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free03Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free03Value = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free04Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free04Value = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free05Name = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.free05Value = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.comment = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.cityCode = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.position = new GpsPosition();

        this.recId = 0;
        this.recStatus = -1;
        this.recCreated = DateTime.UNKNOWN_PC.clone();
        this.recCreatedBy = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.recCreatedByProg = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.recChanged = DateTime.UNKNOWN_PC.clone();
        this.recChangedBy = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.recChangedByProg = StringHelper.emptyString;
        this.usage = new AddressPropertyUsage(AddressPropertyUsage.VERSION3_ALL);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with the `.substring(0)` calls?

This creates another object with the same underlying char array as the original, which I can see might have tempted you to use it.  But why do you need another object anyway?  Strings are immutable, so both instances of `Address` can just use the same `String` directly.

And once that's out of the way, you don't need any of the `if` statements, and can directly assign values, e.g.:

```
// No need to create new instances of String...
//  if (this.recChangedBy == null)
//      destination.recChangedBy = null;
//  else
//      destination.recChangedBy = this.recChangedBy.substring(0);

// so above is replaced by:
destination.recChangedBy = this.recChangedBy;
```

Voila, most/all of the conditionals have disappeared and the cyclomatic complexity has nosedived.

---

(On a different topic, how often are your addresses modified?  I would be very tempted to make this an immutable object, and set all the values in the constructor, which would IMHO make it easier to reason about and use.  Especially compared to constructing an empty address.

Also don't have a contructor that calls a private `init` method - just make the body of that method the constructor.

And I don't think addresses really have 44 fields, this seems like a [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).  Your code would likely be clearer if the `Address` class only represented an address, and the bank details go to an `Account` class, the last change details appear in an `AuditDetails` class, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of those `someString.substring(0)` stuff (43 occurences if I counted correctly). Since strings are immutable in Java just assigning them should be sufficient and thus the checks for null would be obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Address` class contains too many fields. Ideally you should split your object into many small objects like: `BankInfo`, `RecInfo`, `PhoneInfo`, `FreeValues`, etc. And then let your `Address` Class contains variables to these objects.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else who's said that you shouldn't be trying to copy the strings, and that not doing so lets you get rid of the conditionals. But it's worth adding this: If you *did* need to do that conditional copying -- e.g., if those things weren't strings but some other kind of object -- then you would be well advised to factor out the repeated logic:

```
String copyUnlessNull(String s) {
  if (s==null) return null;
  return s.substring(0);
}

void copyTo(Address destination) {
  // ...
  destination.recChangedBy     = copyUnlessNull(this.recChangedBy);
  destination.recChangedByProg = copyUnlessNull(this.recChangedByProg);
  // ...
}
```

For the avoidance of doubt, the above is **not** the right solution in this particular case -- you should just not bother with the substring() stuff at all, and then you don't need the conditional logic -- but whenever you find yourself writing the same code over and over, you should look for a way to write it only once and use it repeatedly.